# How do I extract and check for a date change with Cypress?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, cypress

I have a page that contains some text that tells me when the last time the particular schedule has been updated.  What I need to do is to take that date, make a change to the schedule, and then check the date on the page to see that it has changed/updated.

The problem I am having is understanding how to "extract" the text, that is the date, and then compare it after making a change to the page to say that it is different.  This is the HTML code I want to test against:

```
<div class="link-container last-changed" ng-if="$ctrl.lastUpdatedBy"><small>Page was last updated and by:</small><br />tony itadmin 12:09 01/17/2019</div>
```

I expect to take from the above HTML, "12:09 01/17/2019" and then changed something on the page that I am on.  Then, when the page refreshes, I want to take what the timestamp is then, and then see that it is different than "12:09 01/17/2019"

I'm not sure where to start with this with Cypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern I am using is as follows (although I'm looking to improve it),

```js
it('should update last refreshed text', () => {
  cy.contains('selector-closest-to-text', 'signature text')
    .then(els => {
      const before = els[0].textContent;         // #1 parse the text
      expect(before.length).to.be.above(0);      // #2 in case text is empty
      cy.wait(1000)                              // #3 wait a second for new timestamp
      cy.get('selector-for-refresh-trigger')...  // #4 do something to refresh 
      cy.contains('selector-closest-to-text', 'signature text')
        .should('not.contain', before)           // #5 check has actually changed
        .then(els=> {
          const after = els[0].textContent;      // #6 parse again
          expect(after.length).to.be.above(0);   // #7 in case empty
          expect(before).not.to.eq(after);       // #8 compare
        })
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

#### #1 - parsing the text

In your case it's a bit tricky to get just the date and time. You might just use `textcontent` as I have, if you're not going to test that another user has updated the schedule, but if you just want the date and time this expression might do it

```js
const before = els[0].textcontent.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ')
```

You may want to extract more than just the time of refresh, if so create a plain JS function outside of `it()`

```js
const parseText = (txt) => {
  const split = txt.split(' ')
  return {
    user: split.slice(0,1),
    role: split.slice(1,1),
    timeRefreshed: split.slice(2).join(' '),
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```js
const user = parseText(els[0].textcontent).user
const role = parseText(els[0].textcontent).role
const before = parseText(els[0].textcontent).timeRefreshed
```

#### #3 - waiting for refresh

This is a bit crude but simple. May be improved by waiting for the text to change, `should('not.contain', before)` might be sufficient.
Note `cy.clock()` probably won't work here.

#### #4 - triggering the refresh

I have a button to click, but may be you need to type some text, possibly on another page in which case this step would be multiple lines.

---